# Using WebKit for a desktop application

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

I need to make a desktop application using CSS/HTML5/JavaScript. This application should work cross-platform (Linux/Mac/Windows) and will be distributed as a simple executable (not an installer), where the user simply opens it and can start using it right away. It also needs to work offline, on machines where internet is not accessible.

So I thought WebKit would be the perfect choice. In fact I went ahead, installed Xcode, and in little time I had an executable that opened a window and loaded some CSS/HTML/JavaScript.

However, my issue is that I don't have Linux/Windows machines. I can't afford buying a Windows copy and I don't want to go through the effort of having to install the OS and installing the Visual Studio or whatever thing, and trying to make an executable for those platforms as well.

I was wondering if there was a pre-built executable for each platform that comes with WebKit. So that all I have to do is change the icon of the application, the name and tell it where to get the html/css/javascript and it would make an executable for the platforms I need.

Is this possible? What are my best alternatives?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use **[node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)**.

It uses webkit to render the webpage and execute the Javascript, and you will have access to all the Node.js javascript API (reading/writing files, …)

Comment: Yep I've actually found this not too long ago. Great stuff!

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: Titanium Desktop is an open sourced project nowadays and named "TideSDK"

http://www.tidesdk.org/

You may try both of below. I have used Titanium Desktop: It is webkit based and also becoming an open source project.

http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/

You can also use Embedded Chromium project, but this might require some knowledge on other then HTML/CSS/JS

http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/

Comment: Thanks for the titanium link. But I just spent almost 30 mins trying it out... it's god awful. I'm looking for something simpler. Just a WebKit executable for each environment.

Answer (score 2):

There is certainly some way to do this with Qt / [QtWebkit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit) / [QWebview](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html). But, it is certainly involved.

There is also a [Gtk Webkit](https://live.gnome.org/WebKitGtk).

Answer (score 1):

You would still need an installer, but you can look into Adobe Air. You can build apps that even leverage AS3 libraries as well as make them entirely with HTML5/CSS3 and your flavor of Javascript. Best of luck to you.