# Is there a possibility to run html not in browser?

Tags: html

Is there a possibility to run html not on browser but as an executable,like other languages like java,python and other desktop applications?I know that in android this is possible but in non android is it possible?How?

Comment: ... Where would you want to "run" the HTML file?

Comment: I want it to be executed through other programming languages or if possible other ways without using other programming languages.I want to execute it just like regular desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is markup. It's not executable. You can parse it in a number of ways though with a variety of languages.

You can also use [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) (an app runtime based on Chromium and node.js) to write native apps in HTML and JavaScript (which I think is what you're asking). It also lets you call Node.js modules directly from the DOM.

See also: [Using WebKit for a desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618678/using-webkit-for-a-desktop-application)